# Number of ways of correctly arranging parenthesis

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic, combinatorics, catalan

I've been thinking for a while about this problem:

> What's the number of ways of correctly* arranging 2*n parenthesis.
>   *A correctly arranged sequence of parenthesis has an equal number of open and closed parenthesis at its end and a larger or equal amount of open parenthesis than the closed ones throughout the sequence.

For example, for `n=3`, there are `5` ways: `((())), ()(()), ()()(), (())(), (()())`.

I've been thinking of representing nested parenthesis as trees, but didn't get far.

Comment: Knuth 4a has a paragraph about Catalan numbers.

Comment: Any link to a good combinatorics book?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your example equivalent to the number of [Dyck words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language), which can be counted with combinatorics and will be equal to [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number):

[image]

Comment: Catalan is untaught stuff... Thank you!